# I have visual studio pro 2013 and a message say the trial has expired is there any way to renew the trial?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

What i tried so far is running the visual studio pro 2013 again and then i see:

[image: Extend Trial]

I tried to click there the link on the right but nothing worked so far.

Or the pro version have only trial once ?

Do i need to install the visual studio 2013 express version ?

If i will install visual studio 2013 express i will be able to renew the trial all the time ?

Projects i created on visual studio 2013 pro will run also on visual studio 2013 express ?

Comment: Visual Studio Community is free (alas I can't find the 2013 version, just the 2015) https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx (no it isn't the express edition check the link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to renew the express edition - it is not a trial. 2015 is also available: https://www.visualstudio.com/products/mt238358